# Arreglo de procedimientos c

Tags: c, array, funciones

Necesito crear un arreglo de procedimientos en [c](/questions/tagged/c), lo hice de esta manera pero me da error:

```
typedef void TFunc; 

int main{
  TFunc funciones[25] = {definicion de mis funciones};
}
```

Comment: ¿ Y que error te da ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> #### TL;DR : Salta al segundo "subtema" si te parece aburrido lo que sigue :)

#### Tu error de concepto o desconocimiento del lenguaje:

Eso que te propones, yo personalmente lo considero *mala práctica* debido a la cantidad de argumentos que puede tener una función y etcétera, pero es totalmente posible lograrlo mientras las funciones que vas a almacenar tengan la misma firma<sup>1</sup>.

Voy a empezar desglosando tu problema:

- Al hacer:

  ```
  typedef void TFunc;
  ```

  Estas creando una especie de "alias" para la palabra `void`, lo cual tiene efecto pácticamente *nulo*, porque `void` *(Alias `TFunc`)* se resuelve a:

  ```
  void funciones[25] = { /* ... */ };
  ```

  Y esto, simplemente está mal visto por el compilador de C.
- Y tu segundo error:

  ```
  int main { /* ... */ }
  ```

En C *(Y en prácticamente cualquier lenguaje de programación)* los paréntesis son obligatorios tanto a la hora de llamar, como a la hora de definir o declarar a una función, por lo qué eso simplemente genera errores de compilación<sup>2</sup>.

#### Bien, ahora a resolver tu problema.

Para empezar, debemos reconocer la firma de funciones que queremos que tenga el array de funciones que vamos a construir, en mi caso, he seleccionado `int Funcion(int);`, para hacerlo sencillo.

1. Creamos un `typedef` para mejorar la vista:

   ```
   typedef int (*TFunc)(int); /* Creamos un "alias" para el puntero a función */
   /* El alias definido arriba es una función que retorna un entero 
      y acepta un entero como argumento, puedes cambiarlo como necesites. */
   ```
2. Definimos algunas funciones que *cumplan* con la misma firma<sup>1</sup> que el "alias" definido anteriormente:

   ```
   int EsMinuscula(int c) {
     return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
   }
   int EsDigito(int c) {
     return (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
   }
   int EsControl(int c) {
     return (c >= 0 && c <= ' ');
   }
   int EsMayuscula(int c) {
     return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
   }
   ```

   Tenemos algunas funciones :D, ahora vamos a crear nuestro arreglo de punteros de función<sup>3</sup>
3. Ahora vamos a lo que queremos lograr! Crear el arreglo de funciones<sup>4</sup>:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void) { /* <- Eh que no se te olviden los paréntesis! */
     /* Creamos arreglo para las funciones :) */
     TFunc MisFunciones[] = { 
       EsMinuscula, EsDigito, EsControl, EsMayuscula
     };

     /* Vamos a hacer una prueba :) */
     char *Cads[] = { 
       "Es Minuscula: ", "Es Digito: ", "Es Control: ", "Es Mayuscula: "
     };

     printf("Escribe un caracter (UNO SOLO) y presiona enter: ");
     int Chr = fgetc(stdin);

     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       printf("%s %s\n", 
              Cads[i], MisFunciones[i](Chr)? "si": "no"); 
     }

     return 0;
   }
   ```

Y ya estamos listos con el tema de los punteros a función.

Como verás, no se puede agregar la definición de una función dentro de la expresión utilizada para instanciar un arreglo estático, C es un lenguaje de alto nivel, sin embargo está diseñado para que todo lo que se quiera utilizar, deba estar presente antes de usarse, o, por lo menos, tener su nombre por algún lugar *(Declarar/Crear prototipos)*.

Saludos ^^

---

#### Referencias

<sup>1</sup>: Cantidad de argumentos y tipo de retorno de cualquier función. 
<sup>2</sup>: Vease [ideone](https://ideone.com/TcZ6tn).
<sup>3</sup>: [Punteros a función](http://sopa.dis.ulpgc.es/fso/cpp/intro_c/introc78.htm)
<sup>4</sup>: Te dejo un [repl.it](https://repl.it/@IamNaCl/CAnswer) para que pruebes :)